# Connecting to a private subnet from a GCP service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to reach a server in a private subnet that only has an internal IP from GCP cloud build. Is there something I need to do in order to allow traffic to be routed from google services to my private subnets or see my private DNS zones? Thanks in advance for the help!

**Additional Details**
I am trying to hit it via HTTP through an internal load balancer: Step #1 - "Auth to Vault": Error authenticating: Put http://10.16.6.33:8200/v1/auth/gcp/login: dial tcp 10.16.6.33:8200: i/o timeout

Comment: By what method are you trying to reach this server? Show your Cloud Build config files.

Comment: I am trying to hit it via HTTP through an internal load balancer: `Step #1 - "Auth to Vault": Error authenticating: Put http://10.16.6.33:8200/v1/auth/gcp/login: dial tcp 10.16.6.33:8200: i/o timeout`

Comment: AFAIK, today it's not possible. But, stay tuned!

Comment: Please edit your question with new details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Build is a Google service located in Google controlled VPCs. Your internal load balancer is located in your VPC which Google Cloud Build cannot access.

At this time, Google Cloud does not offer a "VPC Connector" supporting Cloud Build accessing resources in your VPC using [RFC 1918](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses) private addresses.

Comment: This unfortunately appears to be the right answer at this time. GCP support team did give me this as an alternate approach - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/remote-builder

Answer (score 1):

you would have to allow your subnet to talk internal Google resources-

Go to VPC > networks > subnet > Enbale `Private Google Access`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have that setting enabled and I can talk to google services from the subnet. I am trying to connect to a VM in the private subnet from Cloud Build.